# Usage of preposition in "do this TO your computer", "do this WITH information"

Tags: prepositions

I need the clarification of these two particular instances.

> Do this *to* your computer when you finish using it.
>   Do this *with* information that you don't want to keep on your computer.

What rule am I to use in order to choose the right preposition?

Comment: There are entire books on English prepositions but it is against site policy to make specific recommendations. You can search for `English prepositions` on a well-known online bookstore.

Comment: well-known to whom?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I don't think it's against site policy to _make_ specific recommendations, none that I can recall anyway. It **is** against policy for _askers_ to request resources/book recommendations, though. Just a minor clarification.

Comment: @Yukatan, use the `@` character to [ping a user](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4794/why-dont-my-comments-get-answered/4795#4795), eg. `@Em.` Also, please ask one question (about one problem) per post. And please edit your post to make clarifications. Remember to include details about your confusion or concern so that visitors and answerers can have a clear idea of your problem. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Comment: The "rule" would be  something like this: do something to something else. do x with y. So, in fact, you already know these points.

Answer (score 2):

The object of **to** in your example is a thing *directly acted-upon*.  You turn the computer off.  But **to** has many other semantic functions.

The object of **with** in your example is a thing *involved in* the action you take. You throw the information away. You put it in the trashcan. Ditto for **with** : it has many semantic functions too.

> Oh no. What did you do **to** the cat?
>   -- I painted it blue.
>
> How did you erase the chalkboard? It's so nice and black.
>   -- I erased it **with** a felt eraser and then wiped it **with** a damp cloth.
>
> What shall we do **with** the cat now that you have painted it blue?

That last question:  what action shall we take *involving* the cat or *respecting* the cat or *vis-à-vis* the cat?<sup>†</sup> We are not going to do anything directly to the cat, but we are going to take some action in which it will participate or be involved:

We will **give** the cat **away**.

The cat has not been changed intrinsically. Nothing has been done **to** it by giving it away.

<sup>†</sup> Thinking on the etymology of **respect** and **regard** in the context of **with** and **vis-à-vis** will give you insights into the semantics of the pronoun.

Comment: I don't see how your example with 'with' illustrates my question with the same preposition. I take it you're talking about the phenomenon of the so called instrumental case because the example you give is what it is as in: to write with a pen, to take pictures with a camera, to cut with a knife, to fish with a net.. but to do smth with informarion is in my opinion a different kind of matter, am I mistaken in thinking so?

Comment: I can add another example of "involved in" the action in some way. But you could write a dissertation on **with**.  Your request for a single rule is shall we say overly optimistic.

Comment: all the examples I have given above in the comment - not the original question - are translated into Russian using thе so called instrumental case but not the examples with the information or the cat.. the examples of felt eraser and damp cloth also fall under the category of the instrumental case.

Comment: and I guess the cat is also directly acted upon though it isn't altered in any way due to this action.. does the given computer undergo any changes intrinsically due to the action of switching it on/off?

Comment: The computer is intrinsically off or on.  Its essential state changes. The cat changes its color.  That's an attribute of the cat per se.  The cat's location is not an attribute of the cat per se.   In English, back when it had declensions more than a millennium ago, **wið** could be used with genitive, dative, and accusative.

Comment: It had a wide range of not wholly unrelated meanings depending on the case.